# How to initialize a string in java without causing the initialization to cause problems in the program?

Tags: java, string-concatenation, postfix-notation, null-character

I recently wrote a program to convert a string from infix to post-fix in java!
To do that i used two strings `'s'` and `'p'`.
I initialized both strings with `'NULL'`.
Then i got the value of s from user using Scanner class.

```
s=s1.nextLine();
```

so if user enter `"a+b"`, then s has the value `"a+b"`. Note that `'NULL'` is no longer the part of the string!

Now I manipulate p using the concatenation operator '+' like:

```
p = p + '*';
```

I do get my post-fix string:
i.e.

```
ab+.
```

Problem is that this time, NULL does not disappear!
The value of p is:

`"nullab+"` instead of `"ab+"`.

Now I know my concatenation operator is causing problems! It adds to the string!

But java [eclipse indigo] does not let me use an operator without initializing it first!
What do I do? Please help!

Thank you

Anuj Kalra

Comment: Imagine null.toString() will get "null". Is there any reason for not giving an init value? an empty string is a valid init value.

Answer (score 3):

You can initialize the string to empty string to start with:

```
String str = "";
```

The issue with `null` is that string concatenation with a `null` reference will convert it to `"null"` string and then perform the concatenation.

Comment: WOW! I thought this wasn't allowed! I did as you said! Needless to say that it worked! Thanks a lot! Really liked your explanation!--Thanks once again!